# writing down a multi valued function

Tags: multivalued-functions

Supposing a function can assume any value under a curve. As an example, we have a curve f(x). However, my actual function is that for a given value of x, the value y can be anything lower than f(x).

How would I write down this multi-valued function? And is calculating derivative of this function possible?

Comment: You mean the value can be in a range? That's not a function

Comment: yes. That is not a function in the true sense. But can it be written down, say as a complex function?

Comment: Do You mean something like $\Phi:D\rightarrow \{[0,r]:r\in\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}\},x\mapsto [0,|f(x)|]$ where $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is the domain of the function $f$? For a derivative You would need at least some kind of metric on the codomain of this function $\Phi$ though.

Comment: Cool! What kind of metric though?